# invalid_grant Google OAuth

Tags: google-maps-api-3, meteor, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to authentiate through Google's OAuth, but I'm having problems establishing a connection to their API

My client code:

```
'click #addChannel': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var userId = Meteor.userId();
    var options = {
      requestPermissions: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit',
      ],
      requestOfflineToken: true
    };

    Google.requestCredential(options, function(token) {
      Meteor.call('userAddOauthCredentials', userId, token, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
        console.log(result);
      });

    });
```

My server code:

```
userAddOauthCredentials: function(userId, token) {
    check(userId, String);
    check(token, String);

    var config = ServiceConfiguration.configurations.findOne({service: 'google'});
    if (!config) {
      throw new ServiceConfiguration.ConfigError();
    }

    console.log(token, config);

    var endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    var params   = {
      code: token,
      client_id: config.clientId,
      client_secret: OAuth.openSecret(config.secret),
      redirect_uri: OAuth._redirectUri('google', config),
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    };

    try { <------------------------------------------------------ this fails
      response = HTTP.post(endpoint, { params: params });
    } catch (err) {
      throw _.extend(new Error("(first) Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. " + err.message),
                     {response: err.response});
    }

    if (response.data.error) { // if the http response was a json object with an error attribute
      throw new Error("(second) Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. " + response.data);
    } else {
      return {
        accessToken: response.data.access_token,
        refreshToken: response.data.refresh_token,
        expiresIn: response.data.expires_in,
        idToken: response.data.id_token
      };
    }
```

The above throws a `[400] {   "error" : "invalid_grant" }` error.

Most of the above code I got from how the meteor accounts-google packages logs in a user (which works fine in my application). Link to that:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/87e3c6499d5eacce62f10faefe9ce49c77bb03ee/packages/google/google_server.js

Any advice on how to proceed from here?

Much appreciated

UPDATE1:

I get these warnings in my log

```
W20150318-09:11:42.532(1) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20150318-09:11:42.532(1) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20150318-09:11:42.533(1) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20150318-09:11:42.534(1) (oauth_server.js:398) Error in OAuth Server: Match error: Expected string, got undefined
```

Comment: Just making sure, but you've generated your own clientID and clientSecret, correct? 400 errors are typically due to incorrect parameters on a request, so I suggest trying to trace which method is causing the error and make sure it is called correctly.

Comment: Yes I have generated those. Also it's not my application tha's generating the error, but it is returned from the google API

Comment: Do you happen to have any network traces of the queries to google OAuth? Also, are you getting an authorization code from your client and are seeing the error during code exchange?

Comment: I just noticed I get some weird warnings in my server log, updated post

Comment: any luck figuring this out?  I'm having the same issues and have been trying to figure this out for hours.  found some old SO posts that said, despite the naming, we need to supply a service email as the client_id.   tried that, and still no luck (those posts were from 2013 so that specific issue may have been fixed).

Comment: Fwiw I've been using bozhao:link-accounts to solve my problem.  Might be of use to you

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your **var params** to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. Please find the below code to parse as i done in **php**

```
   $fields_string="";
    foreach($params as $key=>$value) 
    { 
         $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```

Now the $filed_string will contained the parse of params array.